# How do I set up Visual Studio Code in the taskbar to show the recent workspaces?

Tags: visual-studio-code, directory, windows-10, workspace, taskbar

I just installed [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) on my new Windows 10 PC and pinned it to the taskbar. When I right-clicked on the VS Code Icon on my old PC it suggested to open the recently opened workspaces. But now it only shows *'Visual Studio Code'* and *'Remove from Taskbar'*. I added VS Code from this Path to the taskbar: `C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe`.

**This is the result of right-clicking the Icon in the taskbar:**

[image: VS Code displaying the wrong actions]

**But I want it to also show the recently opened workspaces like this:**

[image]

**Technologies:**

- Windows 10 Home
- Visual Studio Code 1.51.1

Answer (score 9):

[image: Windows Description]

Desktop right click ->Personalize ->Start ->Show recently opened items in Jump Lists on Start and Taskbar, turn this on.
You need to enable this feature and open some Visual Studio projects before you can find it in the recent projects in the taskbar.

As you said, the recent list in the taskbar is not related to the "Open recent" in the Open Project interface of Visual Studio. The former is the historical operation record of Windows.

If you want to delete the records in the recent list, you can right-click the project name and select Remove from list.